# HTML CSS Horizontal Layout Scaling

Tags: html, css, scale, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to make a horizontal layout (with columns) where the content scales based on the browser window **height**.

I came across answers about perfect ratio based on width, but I want to have an infinite width (as the amount of content won't always be the same).

Is this possible just using HTML/CSS?

Comment: In short, yes it is possible... What exaclty don't you understand from those pages? Your first URL looks like excactly what you describe here and comes with complete code samples.

Comment: The first URL says nothing about content scaling. When I try to change the CSS to respond to browser height, instead of width, nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be hard to maintain the aspect ratio with css, but if you set the height of the maincontent box to 90% and the height of the containers to 100%. They should respond to 
the browser window. But only in height, never in width.

From there you can use javascript to set the with to be `<height> * 1.5` (or similar) you will have to do this in the document ready event, but also in the window resize event.

Comment: Thanks, I've never learned javascript so I was trying to do my best with CSS, but I guess I'll just give it a shot in javascript.